# Spring use configuration and properties from WEB-INF in a integration test?

Tags: spring, configuration, integration-testing

I'm using spring 3. I would use the beans configuration I have in my webapp (`WEB-INF/app-context` ..etc) in my integration tests.

is that possible? What do I need to add to my test context (`IntegrationText-context.xml`) (if that's the right place) to do it?

I've tried  `@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:WEB-INF/app-context/*.xml")` in code but I get FileNotFound..

Essentially I'm trying to reuse the config of the webapp in an integration test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place your appcontext in your regular classpath.

Add a new context to your WEB-INF that imports your appcontext from your classpath. So your context in the WEB-INF only wraps your standard context. The wrapper can be initiated through the web.xml and your unit test has access to the standard file.

Use

```
<import resource="classpath:PATH_TO_YOUR_REAL_CONTEXT.xml"/>
```

in your wrapper context for loading the real context.